# How to fire a local notification in backround mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, background-process

After fetching new data in background, if any, I want to fire a local notification. I did this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotifitacionSetting:)]) {

        [application registerUserNotifitacionSetting:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil]];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void) application:(UIApplication *) application performFetchWithCompletionHandler: (void(^) (UIBackgroundFetchResult)) completionHandler {

    [self SendNotification];

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

}

-(void) SendNotification {    
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    [notification setAlertBody:@"My text"];
    [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30]];
    [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    notification.category = @"my category";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

In settings project I set Background Fetch and Remote Notification.
When debugging logs in `-(void) application:(UIApplication *) application performFetchWithCompletionHandler: (void(^) (UIBackgroundFetchResult)) completionHandler` not displayed.

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please re-format your code. Local and remote notifications are different, you can't send a local and expect to receive a remote...

Comment: `performFetcWithCompletionHandler`: if you copied your code, you have a typo there, it should be `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`.

Comment: I made a typo in the text "performFetcWithCompletionHandler".corrected

Answer (score 0):

In swift if you able to convert it then , this would be perfect iOS 8.3 
(swift 1.2)

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    _ = NSDate()
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: (Time in seconds))
    notification.alertBody = "Alert Body"
    notification.alertAction = nil
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Comment: The notifications work for me. I need the notification shall run in the background.

Comment: Look, your code will execute only once when exiting the application. And I need the application with a certain period automatically run in the background and made the notification.

Comment: then i think you should apply parse push notification that will work for you just fix your issue

Comment: or you can do by is set a default time in     UIDatePIcker and add it to     app delegate

Comment: The theme of this issue: a local notification in backround mode.  
The answer to my question I no received, so I can not close the topic

Comment: It's a bit late, but i think this should work. In the performFetchWithCompletionHandler, create a background task like this: task = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:task];  and then call [self sendNotification]
        task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];